# Aligning memory address of specific pragma packed struct member?

Tags: c++, gcc

I have a struct with data members with types of different lengths (some ints, some words, some just single bytes). The struct is  packed (using #pragma pack(1)).

My question is: Is it possible to have one of the struct's data members memory address be aligned in memory (for example, have the address be divisable by 16)?

I know it is possible to align the whole struct (or in other words, its first member) using **attribute**. I want to know if it's possible to align a specific member and not just the first one.

Basically I need the struct to be packed (every member follows the previous one without padding) and I need that the address of one of the members, not the first one, be divisable by 16.

Comment: If the type's size isn't a multiple of 16, this would never work for arrays.

Comment: Probably, by aligning the whole structure, and then, with calculator in hand, adding the correct number of padding bytes... If you can't afford padding in the structure, you can enclose it in another structure and add padding there. Also, you can move the member to the beginning and align the structure then.

Comment: The aligned member would probably introduce padding.

Comment: @Jarod42: The "neatest" variant would be to have the aligned member to be at precise address, and the whole (unaligned) structure moved accordingly. Say, you want to align the second byte of a structure composed of two bytes. The structure would start at align+15 address.

Comment: @Omer: Out of curiosity, what do you need this for?

Comment: @SF.: But the alignment should also respect restriction introduced by  array of that struct.

Comment: @SF what you described is what I want. Having the aligned member be at an aligned address, and the rest of the struct move accordingly. I'm looking for a nice way to do it too. I need it for reasons too long to explain here (can't avoid it though).

Comment: Could you rearrange your members to have the aligned member as first member ?

Comment: No, members must stay in current order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any possibility to align structures with an offset. You must create the offset (padding) by yourself.

```
typedef struct __attribute__((packed)) special_align {
    char misc[3];
    int align_me;
};

typedef struct __attribute__((packed, aligned(16))) pad_container {
    char padding[13];   //16-3
    struct special_align data;
};
```

Of course accessing the struct will become more cumbersome.
If you don't want to calculate by hand how much padding you need, you can use the `offsetof()` macro. In the example `offsetof(struct special_align,align_me)` will return 3, that is to be substracted from the align size. (of course if the offset is greater than align, you must use a corresponding pad size multiplier. `

```
 pad_size = (sizeof(special_align) * align_size - offsetof(special_align,align_me)) % align_size;
```

Comment: This is huge help. Thanks. The solution so far was dirty and used run-time calculations. This will allow me to do it much more nicely.

Comment: note for the pad size calculation you don't need a multiplier as huge as `sizeof(special_align) * align_size` but you need a multiplier of align_size greater than sizeof(special_align) (to avoid all the mess with negative modulo). It gets normalized to least sufficient amount by `% align_size` anyway, but finding 'least multiplier greater than' is considerably more complex than 'some multiplier greater than' and shouldn't cause trouble as long as size*offset_size doesn't exceed MAX_INT, which would only be case with really enormous structures.

Comment: I showed this to someone and he told me the padding size can simply be (alignment - (offset % alignment)) and it seems to me he is right

Comment: But how can one automate this? You'd get "*invalid use of incomplete type*" if you try to put the formula inside the padding definition (chicken/egg situation) :-(

Comment: @RustyX: I guess this will require some clever programming in the C Preprocessor language :) Since the structures are pretty much fixed at the compilation time, the size of the padding must be determined before compilation - at preprocessing time. Don't ask me how to write that though. I'm pretty poor at C Preprocessor. I guess that's a good subject for SO question though. Write the (non-working) piece in C and ask how to convert it to preprocessor directives :)

Answer (score 0):

`#pragma pack(1)` is nasty -- once it is set for a given structure, it will apply to every member of that structure. None of `alignas`, `__attribute__((packed, aligned(8)))`, `std::aligned_storage`, `std::aligned_union`, `#pragma pack()` constructs *inside that structure* will affect the alignment, the original packing will be maintained for the whole structure (an intermediate `#pragma pack()` will apply to any inner structure that follows, but the outer structure will be packed with its original packing).

So the only solution is to pack your structure manually, by adding padding bytes where necessary.

I'm using something like this, it triggers a compiler error and also shows what the (incorrect) alignment is:

```
template<int s> struct OffsetIs;

template<int N>
struct CheckAlignment {
  static constexpr size_t ok = sizeof(OffsetIs<N>);
};

template<>
struct CheckAlignment<0> {
  static constexpr bool ok = true;
};

#pragma pack(1)
struct MyStruct
{
  char a;
  //char pad[3]; // uncomment to make it compile
  long x;
};
#pragma pack()

static_assert(CheckAlignment<offsetof(MyStruct, x) % 4>::ok, "Alignment of x is wrong");
```